# How to get the value of the checked radiobutton in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, gridpanel

I have four `RadioButtons` in a grid panel, but when I do this:

```
<GroupBox x:Name="radioButtons">
    <RadioButton Content="1" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,45,0,0" Name="status1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton Content="2" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,67,0,0" Name="status2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton Content="3" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,89,0,0" Name="status3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton Content="4" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,111,0,0" Name="status4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</GroupBox>
```

It says that:

> Error 1   The object 'GroupBox' already has a child and cannot add 'RadioButton'. 'GroupBox' can accept only one child.

And the last three `RadioButtons` say:

> The property 'Content' is set more than once.

What's wrong with my `GroupBox`? Furthermore, in my code I want to access the `RadioButton` that is checked (preferably as an `int`). How do I do this? I tried to look in Google and I found a lot of results, but I couldn't understand any of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GroupBox` can only hold 1 item, hence the error about trying to set the `Content` property of the `GroupBox` multiple times.

So, make that a Layout item and then put the `RadioButton`s inside it. Now, you set the `Content` once, which is the `StackPanel`, and that Layout item can hold many children -> `RadioButton`s.

```
<GroupBox x:Name="radioButtons">
  <StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Name="status1"
                  Height="16"
                  Margin="10,45,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Content="1" />
    <RadioButton Name="status2"
                  Height="16"
                  Margin="10,67,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Content="2" />
    <RadioButton Name="status3"
                  Height="16"
                  Margin="10,89,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Content="3" />
    <RadioButton Name="status4"
                  Height="16"
                  Margin="10,111,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Content="4" />
  </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

As for your second question, [Christian Mosers WPF Tutorial.net](http://wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html) has a decent sample. If you don't understand it, you maybe should look at the topics `Binding` and `Converter`, first.

A very crude way to be notified of `RadioButton` checked in a non MVVM way:

```
private void RadioButtonChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
  if (radioButton == null)
    return;
  int intIndex = Convert.ToInt32(radioButton.Content.ToString());
  MessageBox.Show(intIndex.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Then, in each of your `RadioButton`s in xaml, add `Checked="RadioButtonChecked"`.

Comment: thanks it really helped me! can u direct me how to get who is checked into the code?

Comment: I added a link to the last part of my answer. http://wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html is a pretty decent sample of achieving what you need.

Comment: added a function tied into Checked event of RadioButton. intIndex should be an int value provided the Content of RadioButton is set accordingly

Comment: first of all thanks for ur help! secondly, I dont know how to bind it to my main code because I connect my xaml to my main with this code:     <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Name="mainWindowVM"/>
    </Window.DataContext> and my MainWindowViewModel allready inherit DependencyObject so I cant inherit IValueConverter..

Comment: You dont make your ViewModel implement the IValueConverter. Create a seperate class for it. Exactly like how the example shows in that link called "EnumMatchToBooleanConverter". <- is a seperate class!!! Now in your MainWindowViewModel you will have a Property called "CurrentOption" of string type. This will get the string set to whatever is in the corresponding RadioButton's CommandParameter when checked

Comment: at the code:     <Window.Resources>
        <EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
    </Window.Resources> I get the next error: Error 1 The tag 'EnumMatchToBooleanConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. I did a class in the name EnumMatchToBooleanConverter ..

Comment: well thats because you need to provide the namespace under which you have that class. in your Window do you have a xmlns:local... ? you need to provide the namespace the converter class is declared in

Comment: "A very crude way to be notified of RadioButton checked in a non MVVM way" - what's the MVVM way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want many elements or controls then you have to put them in layout containers.

- Grid
- StackPanel
- DockPanel
- WrapPanel
- Etc.....