# Using a set of RadioButton as selector

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I have 4 `RadioButtons` and a method that I want to behave differently depending on the selected `RadioButton`. How could I do this simple task? Should I bind each `IsChecked` state to a bool in my `ViewModel` or there is a better way?

I think that if I had more different options I would do it with a `ComboBox` and binding its selected index to a int property in my ViewModel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value of the checked radiobutton in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036469/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-checked-radiobutton-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating an Enum for these options:

```
public enum MyOptions
{
    Option1,
    Option2,
    Option3
}
```

Then create a property in the ViewModel which holds a value from this Enum:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyOptions SelectedOption {get;set;} //NotifyPropertyChange() is required.
}
```

Then bind these `RadioButtons` using the [`EnumToBoolConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15364725/643085)

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding SelectedOption, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Option1}"/>
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding SelectedOption, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Option2}"/>
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding SelectedOption, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Option3}"/>
```

Then, you determine which option is selected by a simple `switch` in the ViewModel:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
   switch (SelectedOption)
   {
      case MyOptions.Option1:
           ...
      case MyOptions.Option2:
           ...
      case MyOptions.Option3:
           ...
   }
}
```